# How many ways are there to seat $n$ married couples around a round table such that men and women alternate and each women is not

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many ways are there to seat $n$ married couples $(n>3)$ around a round table such that men and women alternate and each women is not adjacent to her husband .

My attempt

Total ways in which men and women are alternate $=(n-1)!n!$

Total ways i which husband and wife are alternate $=2(n-1)!$

If we subtract the above two then we are left with the case when all the husband wife are not adjacent but we are left with the cases when few of them are together .  Please Help !

Comment: Look up the menage problem